# I need a macro for outlook 2010 that lets me choose which email account i send from when i press send

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, macros

in my work i have two accounts. One is personal and one is generic. Our manager would like us to send most emails from our generic account.

I currently have a macro set up so that when i press send a box pops up asking me if i would like to encrypt my mail. I wonder if it would be possible to have another macro which behaves the same as this but lets me choose which account i am sending my message from.

Your help is much appreciated

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but it may be simpler to use (definitely easier to implement).  You can enable a **From:** button at the top of your compose window, just above the **To:** and **CC:** fields.

[image: Outlook From]

This will enable you to see which email it is defaulting to, and to quickly change which email you want it to send from.  To enable the **From:** button, go to the **Options** tab on a new email message.  There is a button that says **From** in the section **Show Fields** on that tab.  Enabling it should keep it visible on all future messages until you deactivate it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do have the From button there but as we send that many emails it is too easy to forget. This is the same situation with the encryption. People kept sending emails without encrypting so we got the macro which makes you  choose to encrypt or not before you can send the email.

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2010 if you have multiple accounts in your profile, all you have to do is hit the From button (above "To", near send), then it will let you pick which account the email is "from".

[image]

If you want to send most mail from the generic account, set that as your default in Backstage View.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We do have the From button there but as we send that many emails it is too easy to forget. This is the same situation with the encryption. People kept sending emails without encrypting so we got the macro which makes you  choose to encrypt or not before you can send the email.